# Unit testing a custom Web API MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I have [extended the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://gist.github.com/andreea-anastasescu/6248104#file-gistfile1-cs) in order to generate "root" objects in the JSON for types that are [decorated with a custom attribute](https://gist.github.com/andreea-anastasescu/6248117#file-gistfile1-txt).

How would I unit test this formatter? I am especially interested in how to check the `WriteToStreamAsync(..)` method.

Comment: Can you compare the generated output with the expected output?  Just check if your root elements are generated as expected (even file content comparison should do the job).  There is in general no need to test the internals of your formatter as long as it produces the results you expect.

Comment: I would still like to test it...

Comment: this is my test code - which breaks on stream.Position = 0...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/andreea-anastasescu/6248798#file-gistfile1-txt

Comment: I created a project with your code.  I used NUnit instead of MSTest.  I created a class called `TestItem` with one property `Property` and ran your code.  `stream.Position` was 30.  When I debugged I saw that `rootFieldName` was null, meaning that it calls `base.WriteToStreamAsync` instead of your code.  What do you see when you debug?  What do you put in your `TestItem` class?  What is your `rootFieldName`?

Comment: I forgot to set the `Title` on your attribute on `TestItem`.  I am able to get the same result as you know.  It seems your writer has been disposed off before you return back.

Comment: When I commented out `writer.Dispose();` the test runs fine.  I don't know if that is something you would like to do though?

Comment: When you call `writer.Dispose()` you also dispose of your `stream` which the writer is using, which you then are unable to read when calling `stream.Position`.  I must admit to not being an expert on async testing, so for all I know this could be a problem only when you call the code synchronously.  What is the behavior when you run this code integrated and asynchronously with everything else?

Comment: the custom formatter just runs fine in the normal environment...

Comment: Very interested in seeing an answer to this. I have a custom media type formatter that outputs collections as an Excel spreadsheet, and I'd really like a straightforward way of unit testing it.

Answer (score 3):

The free O'Reilly ebook [*Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET*](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708) has some very useful, specific advice on [how to test a `MediaTypeFormatter`](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch17.html#_unit_testing_a_mediatypeformatter).

Here is their test method for `WriteToStreamAsync`. (This is the approach I take to [test WebApiContrib.Formatters.Xlsx](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx/blob/d904bb96f47ccb1e137c8e67c7c70a0ba83f018a/test/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Xlsx.Tests/XlsxMediaTypeFormatterTests.cs#L536) and it works well.)

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();

var content = new FakeContent();
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/atom+xml");

var formatter = new SyndicationMediaTypeFormatter();

var task = formatter.WriteToStreamAsync(typeof(List<ItemToSerialize>),
  new List<ItemToSerialize> { new ItemToSerialize { ItemName = "Test" }},
  ms,
  content,
  new FakeTransport()
);

task.Wait();

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var atomFormatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter();
atomFormatter.ReadFrom(XmlReader.Create(ms));

Assert.Equal(1, atomFormatter.Feed.Items.Count());
```

Things to note:

- `FakeContent` and `FakeTransport` are fakes of the `HttpContent` and `TransportContext` classes respectively, code for which you can find in the article.
- `Task.Wait` is used to block execution until the task returned by `WriteToStreamAsync` finishes.
- The output of the formatter is written to a `MemoryStream`, which can then be read and parsed by a suitable formatter/deserialiser so you can make test assertions.

---

Alternatively, you could write a sample controller implementation, start it running and test using a client to call the controller methods. This is what Chris Missal does in [WebApiContrib.Formatting.Bson](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Bson/blob/master/test/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Bson.Tests/BsonFormatterTests.cs#L40).

The controller doesn't need to be complicated:

```cs
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public Item Get(int id)
    {
        return new Item { ID = id };
    }
    // ...
}
```

Set up the server and client:

```cs
[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void fixture_init()
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Formatters.Add(new TestMediaTypeFormatter());
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    );

    var server = new HttpServer(config);

    _client = new HttpClient(server);
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.test.com/");
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/bson"));
}
```

Now, in your tests, call the methods on the client and do what you want with the result:

```cs
var response = _client.GetAsync("test/1").Result;
var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Item>(new HashSet<MediaTypeFormatter> {new TestMediaTypeFormatter()}).Result;
```